# No module named django.contrib.auth when using things that redirect

Tags: django, redirect, importerror

I get the `ImportError "No module named django.contrib.auth"` both when I try to use the `django.shortcuts` `redirect` function and when I try to use:

```
(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
```

I figure it can't be a coincidence that the only place I'm hitting this error is in places where the page is redirected, but maybe it is. I know that the user isn't actually getting logged out, so the error happens before you even get to any redirect code.

Below is my urls.py file.

```
import django.contrib.auth.views
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
import django.contrib.auth

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('karma.views',
(r'^$', 'homepage'),
(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
(r"^opportunities/nearby$", 'draw_map'),


(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
(r'^profile/', include('karmup.profile.urls')),
)
```

Comment: What's the full url config? Do you have a [view prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#the-view-prefix) defined?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are mixing up URL prefixes in your `urlpatterns`.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('karma.views',
  (r'^$', 'homepage'),
  (r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
  (r"^opportunities/nearby$", 'draw_map'),
)
```

Django tries to find views relative to the given URL prefix, in your case `'karma.views'`. Inside this module, there is no `'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'`, hence you get the `ImportError`.

Move the logout URL to a second block, e.g.:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
  (r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
)
```

That should resolve your issue.